# java- what is the property name for setting RMI port via System.setProperty command

Tags: java, rmi

what is the property name for setting RMI port via System.setProperty command

I understand that the property for setting RMI policy file is "java.security.policy"

I would like to know the property for setting RMI port.

Comment: There is no such property. See @ritorujon's answer for how to control the port.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the port for exporting during the object export:
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject((Remote obj, int port)

I don't think that there is a way to set it globally to one specific port (default is 0 -> dynamic allocation).

But if you meant the activator port, then it's:
"java.rmi.activation.port"
System.setProperty("java.rmi.activation.port", port)

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html

Hope that helps...

Comment: Correct. If your class extends UnicastRemoteObject, just call super(port) in the constructor.